# Detect an <a> inside an area using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, area, timeline

My problem is, I got an horizontal slider with years inside so its like a timeline, the years are fetched by a query, at this moment, the user has to scroll by the years and then click one specific year and the information on the website will filter.

Is there a way to detect the year that is in the center of that horizontal slide? Maybe with a hidden area at the center?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: I don't understand you 100%, but anyway. If you have X amount of years, and you want the middle element of this "list", get element X/2 (rounded) and there you go.

Comment: The timeline has a slider and my intentions are to create a static area in the middle of the slider so when i scroll through the years it will select the years that enter that area, for example.. scroll scroll scroll and stop at 1999 in the middle, so its 1999 which will be filtered

Hope i was clearer in this question, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should observe the scroll event of the slider element. you have to measure after each scroll process which element is inside of the visible slider area (I suppose others are hidden by `overflow: scroll` from the CSS, right?)...

you should use a small delay so that the function only triggers when the scrolling was really stopped and not constantly

as it is better to show that with actually working code... checkout my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAkGJ/2/). It is at least working in Chrome but I suppose it will work in other browsers too... when you scroll through the year list and you stop for 50ms this list item that is visible in the visible area of the slider `div` is logged into with `console.log` into the JS console... hope that helps you =)

EDIT: had a small CSS error... fixed and URL updated